# Using Xpath to determine if there are any occurrance of text in any child element?

Tags: python, xpath

I saw a question like this about an XML doc but I have an HTML doc and want to know if it works the same.

I'm trying to loop through many HTML pages and determine if there are any instances of a span element that contains the text "text":

```
//*[@id="all_totals"]/div[1]/div/span[7]//span[text()="Export"]
```

link to image of HTML: http://f.cl.ly/items/290L2v373y3c3P050x2m/Image%202016-05-05%20at%202.59.25%20PM.png

In the above Xpath, the parent element I want ends at the second "div".  I added the rest ("/span[7]...") as the specific element I want to grab.  I want to check if any of the spans contained in the parent element contain the text "text" because, if any of them do, the span element I would want would be [6] instead of [7] (the "text" span is an occasional extra that happens before the one I want leading to the positive increment of 1 place)

I'm sure I'm doing this wrong so any help is greatly appreciated.

Hope this makes sense.  Happy to clarify more if needed!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of or link to the source document(s) you're trying to parse?

Comment: Really a minimal sample in the body of the question is preferred over a link, which can change or break over time.

Comment: Here is a link to the HTML code I'm working with: http://f.cl.ly/items/290L2v373y3c3P050x2m/Image%202016-05-05%20at%202.59.25%20PM.png

It's a link because of the amount of code I wanted to include, to give the fullest picture.

Answer (score 0):

To check “parents“ in any level use **ancestor**

Try something like this (not tested) :

```
 (//*[@id="all_totals"]/div[1]/div
     /span[ ancestor::*/span[contains( text(), "text" )] and position() = 6 
         or position() = 7 ])[1]
```